# SAML or CDSSO based approach feasibility

Tags: saml-2.0, openam, opensso

I was just playing around with OpenAM and found that authentication can be done through SAML as well as cookie based approach of CDSSO. Now my concern is if I am working in domain like banking and healthcare how feasible it would be to go for CDSSO cookie based approach and is their any organization who is practicing cookie based approach in any such domain.

Answer (score 1):

SAML is designed for connecting independent security "domains". The term "domain" in this instance has nothing to do with network domain names, but a rather more nebulous term, meaning a division between security systems. An example to explain a bit better: Company A uses OpenAM to protect its intranet websites, but they also use services from Salesforce. SAML is the obvious choice here - Salesforce isn't going to use a cookie from OpenAM... How could they? You could also use it to interconnect two different systems inside a company (and domain name), like OpenAM and Siteminder, since those two systems can't communicate directly via their cookies.

CDSSO is primarily designed for use inside an organization that could have multiple domains that they protect. They can have multiple policy servers in multiple domains, but all of those servers are managed by the same OpenAM instance, and they all share a common backend. Lots of organizations use OpenAM's (and OAM's, and Siteminder's) CDSSO capabilities. But they use it inside the systems within their control.

In addition, I can't think of a single service provider that would want you to place one of your OpenAM policy servers inside their network. You wouldn't want them touching your server, and they wouldn't (if they are right in the head) trust you to not be dropping a trojan in their network.

TL;DR:
SAML - outside of an administrative domain
CDSSO - inside an administrative domain

Answer (score 0):

SAML is the standards based way of achieving SSO for, Agents is the proprietary way.

SAML does not offer any authorization (which user is allowed access to a given resource) out-of-the box ... that's the backdraw.